# Trim image by number of pixels

Tags: graphics, crop, dimensions

Is it possible to trim an image by a certain number of pixels rather than a length?

I have a set of images that I'm including, and in one figure, a trim of 135 on the bottom works nicely, but a second version of the same images that has undergone some image processing got saved with a different DPI (not a different size), so the same trim appears to trim them quite differently.

However, both sets of images are 512x384, so is it possbile to just specify a trim in terms of image pixels, e.g. 100px? Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK `pdflatex` supports `px` as length unit. Did you tried using `\includegraphics[clip,trim=0 100px 0 0]{image}`?

Comment: @Martin: you need to first set the pixel width; if the image resolution is 300dpi, `\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1in/300\relax` should do. The default value of 1px is 1bp, i.e., the default resolution is 72dpi.

Comment: @egreg: Ah-hah, that explains things. I was using px initially, but it didn't work the same for both images, so I guess the problem was the pdfdimen variable. If I change this just before a figure that has a different resolution, I assume I should reset it to default right after that figure so it doesn't mess up other graphics. Can you tell me how to do this? I.e. what's the default resolution I should set it back to. I read 72dpi elsewhere, but is this always the case? If not, is there a way to retrieve the current default resolution? Thanks.

Comment: If you change the dimension in a group (the `figure` environment, for example) the setting will be restored when the group is closed. Or say `{\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1in/<res>\relax\includegraphics[...]{...}}`.

Comment: OK, so just to be clear, suppose I have two copies of the same image, one at 96dpi, and one at 300dpi, but both having the same total size (512x384). If I set `\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1in/96\relax`in the figure environment for the first image and `\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1in/300\relax` for the second, then apply a trim of 100px for both, shouldn't this perform a nearly identical trim on them in the final document? Because I tried this and it's clearly a different though similar level of trim. Too big a difference to be rounding error at the pixel level I think. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, `\pdfpxdimen` also works in DVI-mode of pdftex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Summarising the comments as an answer.)

pdfTeX will work with `px` units, but you have to set these up appropriately using `\pdfpxdimen`. This is the physical width of one pixel, and has default value of `1 bp`, meaning that images initially are assumed to be 72 dpi. `\pdfpxdimen` is a low-level dimen primitive, and so is best set using `\dimexpr`:

```
\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1 in/<dpi>\relax
```

where `<dpi>` is the resolution of the image.

With that set correctly, you can then use `\includegraphics` as normal, adding `px` to the values used by the `trim` (or other) key to get the right result.

As an example, consider the two images

[image: 600 dpi]

and

[image: 72 dpi]

which have the same pixel size but different resolution. Using the LaTeX file

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength\fboxsep{0 pt}
\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1 in/600\relax
\includegraphics[clip,trim=0 100px 200px 100px]{Figure-a} % 600 dpi
\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1 in/72\relax
\includegraphics[clip,trim=0 100px 200px 100px,scale = 0.12]{Figure-b} % 72 pdi
\end{document}
```

results in the output file

[image: result]

which shows the result of the trimming - both are the same. (I've scaled the second image so that the two are printed the same size by pdfTeX.)

Comment: If you need this more often I would define a `dpi` option for `\includegraphics`: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{dpi}{%
    \pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1in/(#1)\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[dpi=600,clip,trim=0 100px 200px 100px]{Figure-a} % 600 dpi
\includegraphics[dpi=72,clip,trim=0 100px 200px 100px,scale = 0.12]{Figure-b} % 72 dpi
\end{document}
`