# crop jpg image by pixel

Tags: tikz-pgf, croptrim

After read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23252/70324) SO, I try below code to crop a 3840x2160 jpg file with below code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength\fboxsep{0 pt}
%\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1 in/600\relax
\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1 in/72\relax
\includegraphics[clip,trim=432px 0px 0px 0px,scale = 1]{sample.jpg} % 
\end{document}
```

But after measure with other software, I found the position 440px is not as expect after cropped by above code.

Maybe I am wrong to 1/72 as one pixel. if not, what value should be used to get correct result?

input image:
[image]

When measure the left black bar, the x offset is about 432px. but the output as below (only show the top left part here):

[image]

The circle has been partially clipped wrongly.

Comment: This seems quite accurate: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1in/72\relax
\includegraphics[trim=200px 0px 0px 0px]{example-image.png}
\end{document}`. `example-image.png` has 400×300 pixels and we cut it in two halves here. The dark gray vertical middle line in the original image is two pixels wide; when cut, we only see one column of this line remaining on the left of the image, as expected.

Comment: hmmm, sounds like big size image doesn't work.

Comment: It works as well with `example-image.png` resized to 3840×2880 (thus larger than your image) via `convert $TEXMF/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.png -scale 3840x3840 test-img.png` and the same document as in [my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532882/crop-jpg-image-by-pixel?noredirect=1#comment1347453_532882) after substituting `test-img.png` for `example-image.png`, and `1920px` for `200px` if one wants to trim the left half of the image. I'm afraid there is something on your side, but since you don't allow us to reproduce the problem, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Updated with my test jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Using your `img.jpg` file with

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pdfpxdimen=\dimexpr 1in/72\relax
\includegraphics[trim=432px 0px 0px 0px]{img.jpg}
\end{document}
```

compiled with `pdflatex`, I obtain this:

[image]

I don't see the problem mentioned in your question. At 72 dpi, the 3840 pixels-wide image would be approx. 53 inches wide (or 1.35 m). Thus, in order to prepare the above `.png`, I converted the PDF file using a relatively low resolution:

```
convert -density 40 input.pdf output.png
```

This gives a 1893×1200 output. With a resolution such as 300 dpi or more, the output file would have been very large—way too large to be included here.